# Как перевести массив байт обратно в строку

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который переводит строку в массив байт:

```
public static void Encrypt(string EnterText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < EnterText.Length; i++)
    {
        byte[] s = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(EnterText);
        Console.Write(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Как расшифровать этот массив обратно в строку?

Comment: Без знания default encoding только эвристически.

Comment: Немного по поводу указанного метода. Слово "encrypt" пишется через "y"`. Вызывать метод `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` на каждой итерации вместо вызова один раз до цикла расточительно. Использование индекса `i` до длины строки вместо длины массива `s` звучит нелогично и может быть попросту некорректно, если, например, `GetBytes` будет вызываться для кодировки UTF-8.

Comment: А преобразовывать массив обратно в строку вы собираетесь на том же компьютере? То есть всё сводится к тому, можно ли уверенно использовать ту же кодировку для преобразования обратно.

Comment: Нет. На одном пк строка текста преобразуется в массив байтов и отправляется на другой и уже там расшифровывается .

Comment: Тогда точно стоит "переехать" с кодировки `Encoding.Default` на какую-то конкретную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для преобразования массива байтов в строку существует метод [Encoding.GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Если есть уверенность в том, что на момент преобразования массива в строку свойство [Encoding.Default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) будет возвращать ту же кодировку что и на момент преобразования строки в массив, то достаточно сделать так:

```
private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;

public static byte[] Encrypt(string str)
{
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}

public static string Decrypt(byte[] data)
{
    return encoding.GetString(data);
}
```

Если же желания или возможности надеяться на `Encoding.Default` нет, можно просто использовать конкретную кодировку. Например, UTF-8:

```
private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Наверное что то не так делаю но метод Encrypt возвращает только System.Byte[]

Comment: @Сергей а что он ещё должен возвращать? Принимает строку, возвращает массив байтов.

Comment: Наверное я неправильно описал вопрос. Первоначально он должен возвращать массив '223443222344 ...' записывать в *.txt. файл и отправлять этот файл на другой ПК где стоит программа расшифровки.

Comment: @Сергей полученный массив байтов вы можете записать в файл (например, с помощью метода `File.WriteAllBytes`) или отправить по сети - право ваше. Вопрос был про то как из массива байтов, полученного с помощью метода `GetBytes`, получить обратно строку. Ответ - используя метод `GetString` для той же кодировки.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes просто запишет тоже самое сообщение в файл а мне нужно зашифрованное которое рас шифруется на другом пк

Comment: @Сергей а как это связано с вашим вопросом? В вопросе, напомню, вы получаете байты из строки и никак их не шифруете. И вопрос совсем не про "а каким бы таким алгоритмом мне зашифровать строку?".

Comment: В вопросе метод Encrypt выводит на консоль из строки сообщения массив байт вида "1222322357221434..." через Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes . Вопрос как получить обратно из "1222322357221434" строку текста. Это не шифрование.

Comment: @Сергей это отладочный вывод в консоль. Или вы что - собрались каким-то чудесным образом из консоли выведенные данные потом считывать? У вас **нигде** в коде не хранится строка в виде `"1222322357221434..."`. Хранятся только байты в массиве `s`. Который, ко всему прочему, у вас ещё и не возвращается из метода. Да и вообще - вы прикидывали что будет, если вы сможете получить свою строку? Что если она будет, например, ``"12223"? Как её интерпретировать: как 122 и 23 или как 12 и 223?